# If error, then start loop over with different params?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am working with the Amazon API and when i submit a request, the response is something like `<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="082686322363" IdType="UPC" status="ClientError">` How would i go about continuing through the loop since there is 5 products per xml sheet that have to get parsed. Will something like this work?

```
if ($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship === FALSE) {
    $salesRank = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0];
} else {
    $ASIN = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship->VariationParent->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;
}
```

Maybe something that just checks the ID, and if it = 'Success' continue, If not then skip over it? How would i go about Skipping over the UPC data?
Full Error:

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id = "082686322362" IdType = "UPC" status = "ClientError">
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Invalid UPC identifier 082686322362 for marketplace ATVPDKIKX0DER</Message>
</Error>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

The loop that i am trying to make work:

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($groupedArrays) - 0); $i++){
$xmlFilePath = 'xml/' . $file_name . $i . '.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);

foreach($xml->children() as $items) { 
    if ($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Error) {
        continue;
    }
    $upcTag = $items['Id'] . ',';
    if($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship === FALSE){
        $salesRank = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0] . ',';
    } else {
        $ASIN =  $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship->VariationParent->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN . ',';
    }
        $price = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->Binding->Amount . ',';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please accept and optionally up vote my answer if my answer has done what you need to do.  Thank you!

Comment: i am not able to up vote yet. how do i accept the answer?

Comment: There is a little checkmark thing underneath the down vote arrow http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check for the error tag with something like this to handle your errors:

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($groupedArrays) - 0); $i++){
    $xmlFilePath = 'xml/' . $file_name . $i . '.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);

    foreach($xml->children() as $items) { 
        if ($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Error) {
            continue;
        }
        $upcTag $items['Id'] . ',';
        if($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship === FALSE){
            $salesRank = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0];
        } else {
            $ASIN =  $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship->VariationParent->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;
        }
        $salesRank = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->
            $price = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->Binding->Amount . ',';
    }
}
```

Syntax errors - if PHP is not showing you any errors, you should at least fix it because it is confusing and unclear what you are trying to do with the code:

```
$upcTag $items['Id'] . ',';
```

and this doesn't look right:

```
$salesRank = $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->
```

You don't want to end your line of code with ->

Comment: how would i just skip over the error and do nothing, but just continue?

Comment: please post more of your code.  Do you know about the command `continue;` ? it will let you continue/"skip" within a loop.  Just added `continue;` to my example.

Comment: Would I include that as another foreach in the other foreach loops?

Comment: sorry, thought you realized I had posted only a modification to your code not something totally separate from your code.  Edited post with all of your code included.  It looks like your code has some syntax errors though which I did not fix.

Comment: Where are the errors? if you don't mind me asking of course.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean??  If the Error tag exists as an XML element then it means there is an error.  This `$items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Error` indicates the item has an error and should be skipped.

Comment: i meant syntax errors. I'm sorry for not explaining. I updated the code with an updated version.

Comment: it's possible it's not generating any syntax errors but at the very least it is confusing about the intention and purpose of those lines of code.

Comment: i am working with the amazon API, and they give me XML as a response. i am just breaking down the response and if one UPC has an error, then i didn't want the code to break. Now, I made this part of the code so that i can then export it to a csv file for the client to then see. I also need as much error prevention as possible because i will not always be around when the code is running to see any problems ect.

Comment: as long as your php script is not generating errors and you've double checked the result you want, you will be fine.